# log4net returns 'NOT AVAILABLE' only sometimes for items in HttpContext

Tags: asp.net, logging, asp.net-mvc-5, log4net

The environment is very simple where we're using Asp.Net MVC 5. log4net was configured as per documentation.

The transports used are file, logentries.com and database. And in all instances, the HttpContext items like ClientIpAddress or ServerName are returned as "NOT AVAILABLE" from log4net.

In the attached screenshot you see the logentries examples.

How/Why would it be coming back as this? How do we avoid it? The documentation doesn't seem to have anything on this :(

[image]

Here's what we're using for the conversion pattern settings:

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %level %thread %aspnet-request{ASP.NET_SessionId} %aspnet-request{AUTH_USER} ClientIpAddress='%aspnet-request{REMOTE_ADDR}' %newline%message%newline" />
  </layout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that not all logs are written in a HttpContext. When they do not have a context, you see the log lines you have in the sample. An second explanation could be that you lose the context when you start a new Thread or do async operations. In both cases your log message can help you where the log items originates.

Comment: Ah, in my case it's the 2nd explanation. That particular example is where I'm doing:

     Parallel.ForEach(... _logService.Info("Creating barcode for ....'); 


So having the Parallel loop is losing log4net+HttpContext context, if that makes sense.